# Why my usestate hook value is not updating after onClick event with no error at all?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, map-function

[codeSanbox Link](https://qub76.csb.app/)

However, the browser gives no error but the income state is not updating whenever I add an transaction if the amount is positive.

The income state keeps the sum of all positive amount added and the expense state of all negative amounts added.

I want the functionality that positive transaction amount should go into income container and negative into expense container and on transaction delete button both income and expense state should update according to the deleted transaction.

[image: APP UI]

```
 AddTransaction.js
```

```
import React from "react";

const AddTransaction = ({
  item,
  amount,
  setItem,
  setAmount,
  transaction,
  setTransaction,
  income,
  setIncome,
  expense,
  setExpense
}) => {
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTransaction([
      ...transaction,

      {
        text: item,
        amount: amount,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
      }
    ]);
    setItem("");
    setAmount("");

    transaction.map((trans) =>
      Math.sign(trans.amount) === 1
        ? setIncome(trans.amount)
        : setExpense(trans.amount)
    );
  };
  console.log(transaction);

  return (
    <div className="addtransaction-container">
      <div className="add-trans-header">
        <h4>Add New Transaction</h4>
      </div>

      <form>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label htmlFor="text">Text</label>

          <input
            type="text"
            value={item}
            onChange={(e) => setItem(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter text..."
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-control">
          <label htmlFor="amount">
            Amount <br />
            (negative - expense, positive - income)
          </label>

          <input
            type="number"
            value={amount}
            onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter amount..."
          />
        </div>

        <button type="button" onClick={onSubmit} value="submit" className="btn">
          Add transaction
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddTransaction;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit function should be like that:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const trans = {
      text: item,
        amount: amount,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
    };

    setTransaction([
      ...transaction,
      trans
    ]);
    setItem("");
    setAmount("");

    Math.sign(trans.amount) === 1
        ? setIncome(trans.amount)
        : setExpense(trans.amount)
  };
```

The idea is that you don't need to call `setIncome/setExpense` for all existing transactions, only for the new one.

P.S. Another thing to improve is to update transactions like this:

```
 setTransaction((prevTransactions) => [...prevTransactions, trans]);
```

In this case everything will work smooth. More [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Comment: Yes, but setIncome should add the trans income to the total income: setIncome(income + trans.amount); (and same for the expanse)

Comment: yeah it works...but how to add all the transaction and display their sum dynamically in income container?

Comment: In this case you should do setIncome(prev => prev + trans.amount). The same you do for expense, you just nedd to substract value every time.

Comment: For simplicity, btw, I'd store both exprense and income as positive numbers and just display total expense as {-1 * expense} in order to make it negative

Comment: Becaue your amount is a String, just do `Number(trans.amount)`

Comment: one last.....why my state is string as my intial value is not in double quotes?

Comment: You data from the `<input />` is a String, because everything what's coming from it will be a String

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what you need in your `onSubmit` to tally up your totals:

```
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const new_trx = [
      ...transaction,

      {
        text: item,
        amount: parseInt(amount),
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
      }
    ] 

    setTransaction(new_trx);
    setItem("");
    setAmount("");

      Math.sign(amount) === 1
        ? setIncome(prev => prev + parseInt(amount))
        : setExpense(prev => prev - parseInt(amount))

  };
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-sun-98p8v

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
 const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTransaction((prev) => { 
      const newTransaction = [...prev, {
                  text: item,
                  amount: amount,
                  id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
     }] 

    newTransaction.map((trans) =>
        Math.sign(trans.amount) === 1
          ? setIncome((prev) => prev + Number(trans.amount))
          : setExpense((prev) => prev + Number(trans.amount))
      );
     return newTransaction;
    });

    setItem("");
    setAmount("");
  };
```